# how to set height of gridview programmatically android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I want to set the height of my **Gridview** programmatically in my application.

Is there  any way to implement  that?

I just want to change the gridview height in two particularcases from the code.

**EDIT:**

```
<fragment
     android:id="@+id/mygridview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="10dip"
     class="com.myapp.android.MyGridViewClass" />
```

MyGridViewClass extends Fragment where Gridview is populated.

```
 <GridView
    android:id="@+id/mygridview_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />
```

In myGridViewClass `onViewCreated`, I am inflating the gridview using the code,

```
gridView = (GridView)getView().findViewById( R.id.mygridview_container);
gridAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(context, list);
gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
```

Whenever the view is created I have to check the number of items in the gridview and set the height accordingly.

When I tried setting the layoutParams() for gridview, I got this exception.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #89: Error inflating class fragment
```

Where line 89 corresponds to this line in the fragment
    class="com.myapp.android.MyGridViewClass"

Comment: InflateException generally have a root cause. Please provide the full stacktrace

Comment: Worked correctly this reference link [Gridview height gets cut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481844/gridview-height-gets-cut)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use this, as you want to retain the current `layoutParams`:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = yourGridview.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = 50; //this is in pixels
yourGridview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Edit: If you want to input the height as `dp` instead of pixels, translate the `dp` amount to pixels:

```
public static int convertDpToPixels(float dp, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            dp, 
            resources.getDisplayMetrics()
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Friend, I tried this method too. Not working. I am using a fragment to which I am inflating this gridview. Maybe that is blocking this code. I am getting an `InflateException` for the class specified which is `class="com.myapp.android.MyGridViewClass"`

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work:

```
GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(...);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp=new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width,height);
gridView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: double check the id your using in findViewById

Comment: I am inflating this GridView inside a fragment due to which I am getting an `inflateException`. :(

Comment: Provide more details please... Do you have a ClassCastException or an InflateException? Edit your question with your code and the trace if you need more help.